# Display looks weird in dark scenes

Tags: graphics-card, display, gpu, gaming, displayport

I've got a new display [DELL S2417DG](https://www1.euro.dell.com/content/products/productdetails.aspx/dell-s2417dg-monitor) and it looks really weird in dark gamescenes. I cant really explain it, it just looks really weird.

Take this shot as example:

[image: Example shot]

It's in a dark minecraft cage.

I downloaded and installed the [official driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/product/dell-s2417dg-monitor/drivers). I've set the refresh rate in windows to 165hz and picked the right color profile (the one installed by the *driver*). I tried tuning my brightnes and contrast but that didn't really change anything.
Running a GTX1080 on Windows10 64bit v1903. I cant remember having such issues with my previous Display.

---

Any idea whats going on here?

I already DDU'd my GPU drivers and did a fresh (offline) installatio. Did not help at all.

Ofcourse also tried all the display settings and a factory reset.
I also changed the DP cable and tried all ports on my GPU. Just in case..